# Can't update Select value on update (MUI Select and react-hook-form)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, material-ui

I have been losing my mind over a MUI Select component. It was working fine until I had to use it with `i18next`, which changes my Select data on the rerender. That forced me to use `react-hook-form` with a `Controller` and a `register`.

I am still getting warnings though - every time I change my app's language I get a `MUI: You have provided an out-of-range value` warning.

I can't figure out what else is missing - could anyone help me with that? I'm guessing something's off with my `useEffect`, as when I change the app's language the default value remains as the previous one, and then I get this out-of-range value warning.

Example:

```
FR
"component": {
  "firstOption": "Rouge"
  "secondOption": "Vert"
}

EN
"component": {
  "firstOption": "Red",
  "secondOption": "Green"
}
```

What happens is that if my current language is FR, then my default value is "Rouge", but then as soon as I change the language to EN, the default value should change to "Red" but it's not doing so, it's still "Rouge", then I get this "out-of-range" value warning.

Here is my code:

`Select.tsx`

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Controller, useForm } from 'react-hook-form';
import { SelectChangeEvent } from '@mui/material';

type SelectProps = {
  defaultValue: string;
  options: string[];
};

const Select = ({ defaultValue, options }: SelectProps) => {
  const [anchorEl] = useState<null | HTMLElement>(null);
  const [selectData, setSelectData] = useState('');
  const open = Boolean(anchorEl);
  const { control, register } = useForm();

  const registerData = register('selectData');
  const handleChange = (event: SelectChangeEvent) => {
    setSelectData(event.target.value);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    setSelectData(defaultValue);
  }, [defaultValue]);

  return (
    <Controller
      name="Select"
      control={control}
      defaultValue={''}
      render={() => (
        <Select
          aria-controls={open ? 'select' : undefined}
          aria-expanded={open ? 'true' : undefined}
          aria-haspopup="true"
          id="select"
          {...registerData}
          value={selectData}
          onChange={(e: any) => {
            registerData.onChange(e);
            handleChange(e);
          }}
        >
          {options.map((option) => (
            <div key={option} value={option}>
              {option}
            </div>
          ))}
        </Select>
      )}
    />
  );
};

export default Select;
```

Then when using the component:
`App.tsx`

```
import { useTranslation } from 'react-i18next';
import Select from '../../shared/Select/Select';

function App() {
  const { t } = useTranslation('pages');

  return (
    <div>
      <Select
        defaultValue={t('component.firstOption')}
        options={[t('component.firstOption'), t('component.secondOption')]}
      />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: useEffect runs after every render.  You are rendering the Select with the new options and the old value, which is no longer a valid option.  That should explain the error.

Comment: @KenGregory yes that's exactly the problem - I am not sure how can I fix it though?

Comment: One approach would be to choose values that don't need to be translated.  Render the proper description, but associate them with an identifier that is constant regardless of the user's language.